# How to publish opengraph actions in rails using app access token

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Hi I want publish open graph actions for my rails app. I want to publish simple todo sharing action. I got following code to do that

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:todo
     ?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Now my problem is I want to use app access token to do this post request, but when I use app_token I get following  error.

```
{    "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 2500    }
}
```

I tried above url from browser.I want to know **how to make post request from rails controller** & **how to publish open graph action using app_access token**?

Comment: Try using an access token from this link https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Comment: By the way do you use builtin objects and actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using an app access token, the special id `me` has no meaning.

If you want to publish actions on behalf of a user using an app token, you need to do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/[YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE]:todo
 ?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Note, the user specified in the path must have already granted your app permission to publish actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular HTTP requests and all the information you need is here:

- [Facebook Authentication (server-side flow)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

That said, because you're using Ruby (and Rails) you should consider using one of the ruby Facebook gems e.g.:

- [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)